# Proof of surjection of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$. Consider the map

\begin{aligned}
T_A:\mathbb{F}_c^n&\to \mathbb{F}_c^m\\
X&\mapsto AX
\end{aligned}

I want to show that $T_A$ is a surjection if and only if the rank of $A$ is $m$.
Could someone enlighten me how to start?

Comment: That depends: what's your definition of rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $x \mapsto Ax$ is surjective if and only if every equation of the form $Ax = b$ (for some $b \in \Bbb F^m$) has a solution.